# How many computer languages have more than one extension?

Tags: html

HTML uses **.html** and **.htm** extensions. Apart from HTML, is there any computer language that uses more than one extension

Comment: That has nothing to do with computer languages. That's a file extension.

Comment: @Rob, we have to save our programs, written using **computer languages**, in **files**. So, thought they were related somehow.

Comment: HTML does not use the file extension **.html**. Operating systems and programs do. It is  that software that determines what **.html** and **.htm** means or how it is to be used. HTML plays no part in that. It's a file format, not part of the language. In fact, I'd bet there is no mention of it in the HTML specification at all. (A very quick search just now did not turn up anything.)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: "All" -- it really doesn't matter because you can have as many as you like for any language you want as well as any other person can.

---

First, HTML doesn't use an extension. Nor any other form of instructions be it a readable file or a binary. HTML is a language, a **content**. It's the system that **runs** the content for example webserver for the PHP/Python/CGI/... files mostly if the website is dynamic and browser takes care of the rest (HTML). Or be it [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) or even [binary/library loader](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) for other cases.

Otherwise it's just a content transferred between 2 systems and for example this is why [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) doesn't render your website but returns plain HTML in the console -- it can't interpret it the same way a web browser can (render elements).

## 1. Default files and interpreting content in browser

Extensions don't really matter in this context, it's just a label as a part of a file name. If you name your `index.html` as `hello.world` and change your webserver's default page to be `hello.world` it'll work. At least, depending on the content of your file and resulting [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) response header.

If you don't change it, it's browser's doing that you get the file to your system and that the browser is able to read it. This way browser distinguishes between e.g. PHP files, HTML files and modern browsers even between audio/video and other formats.

Therefore you're able to:

- play MP3 (`Content-Type: audio/mpeg`)
- or play MP4 (`Content-Type: video/mp4`)

as well as read PDF (`Content-Type: application/pdf`) in the same browser -- none of which are HTML (`Content-Type: text/html`).

## 2. Assuming file content by extension (compilers)

If you have a compiler that looks for `*.c` files, in most of them there's either an option to use an extension or to supply a full filename. Some of them plainly assume you use C or C++. C++ allows to use `.h` as header or `.hpp` to make it different from C language.

Some compilers don't care and look at the content, in most of them you are able to specify particular language *and its options even* such as in GCC with [`-x language` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html):

> gcc -x c hello.world
>
> filename: hello.world

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

## 3. Bilingual, multilingual and embedded programs/scripts

Extensions as well as file names don't really matter because it's the content that's processed. As an example check [this amazing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60061/52609) embedding 8 different languages into one program, a new compiler in fact.

There's also similar code-golfing category where you have N languages combined in one file and depending on what interprets/compiles it you get different results e.g. Python + C++ + Bash or similar combos.

My silly approach with pre-processor aka search&replace to have Python exit with code `10` and C with `20`.

```sh
gcc -x c -o hello.bin hello.world 2>&1 1>&/dev/null
echo "Python: $(python hello.world;echo $?), C: $(./hello.bin;echo $?)"
```

```
#ifdef __linux__
#define pass main() {return 20;}
pass
#else
exit(10)
#endif
```

> Note: use [`tcc`](https://bellard.org/tcc/) and rename to `hello.c` to use the same filename: `tcc -run hello.c;echo $?;python hello.c;echo $?`.

## 4. POSIX

Also, with POSIX systems there is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) which allows you to specify the runner/interpreter. Therefore I can do this:

> hello.world

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "Hello world"
```

and switch it to Python if I want to

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello world"
```

## 5. Integrated Development Environments (IDEs)

With the age of IDEs e.g. Eclipse, VS, VS Code, etc, some of them fixed themselves on **specific** extensions to use proper syntax highlighting or in other words, use **one** language lexer to highlight the syntax of the whole file content. However I can as well embed bash, SQL or any other language into a Python script and I might want to make my IDE highlight **both** of the languages ([random related - Java+XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52428583/5994041)). Or I can have >2 languages within a single file.

Some of them support multiple languages and care about the content mainly. Some on the other hand use the old way and you're simply out of luck [because they don't support multiple languages in one file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1751).